# Monitor load of crossdomain.xml file?

Tags: actionscript-3, crossdomain.xml, urlloader

Is there any way to monitor the loading of the crossdomain.xml file?

I'd like report the load times of this file, since it seems to be intermittently taking longer than expected.  There doesn't seem to be an event from URLLoader and Security.loadPolicyFile() doesn't allow any event listeners.

How can I get the load time for a crossdomain.xml file without requiring additional loads of the file?

Answer (score 0):

When I ran into issues with crossdomain.xml, I read some basic stuff about what it was and how you can work with it. This is a "heavily simplified/not entirely true version of it" but it might serve as a guideline.

Crossdomain.xml-loading is owned by 'browser/flash initialization' and tells browser if 'any code' should be allowed to execute or not. Hence you can't really measure it since it's loaded prior to your code and in another environment.

There might be some way of finding it, it might have changed since I last tried to do that several years ago... but...

You can always measure it in another way, last app I used to troubleshoot issues in this area was [Charles Web Debugging Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/).